# Use implicit differentiation to find the derivative of $\arcsin(y+x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Use implicit differentiation to find the derivative of $\arcsin(y+x)$

I have no idea how to proceed. I now that the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ but I don't know how to incorporate that into this implicit differentiation problem.

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$. Can you continue?

Comment: Is there an implicit differentiation problem that you are able to do, Faolan? If the question were, use implicit differentiation to find the derivative of $y^3+xy+x^3$ (with respect to $x$), would you be able to do that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I know how to do that. I'm guessing I'm making it seem more challenging than it actually is

Comment: Yes, probably. It's basically just the chain rule. $${d\over dx}f(y)=f'(y){dy\over dx}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin(x+y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x+y)^2}}\times\frac{d}{dx}(x+y)=\frac{y'+1}{\sqrt{1-(x+y)^2}}$$
It is basically:
$$\frac{d}{dx}g(f(x,y(x)))=\frac{dg}{df}\frac{df}{dx}$$